# Challenging one: Reading paragraph of text into a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to read a paragraph of text into a matrix such that each word is a separate element. The first sentence occupies the first row, the second sentence occupies the second row, and so on, with each word occupying a different column of the matrix. In c++ please

For example the sentences:

```
John likes apples
Jack likes apples
```

would give:

```
[John, likes, apples]
[Jack, likes, apples]
```

This is what my code currently looks like for this segment. I have included the `vector`, `string`, `iostream` and `stdafx` headers. The information I need is on every third line starting at line 2 of the text file, so lines 2, 5, 8, ...

```
Map_Data.open("/Users/Josh/Desktop/PhD/programming/general/RomanianMapData.txt");

vector< vector<string>> child_node_list; // vector of strings that will hold the child node titles for each parent node
vector< vector<int>> edge_length; // vector of int that will hold the edge distances between the parent node and each child node

while (Map_Data.is_open()) // performs actions while file is open
{
    while (getline(Map_Data, line_check)) // checks the number of lines in the txt file
    {
        number_lines++;
    }
    break;
}

Map_Data.close(); // close file so it can be reopened at the beginning to get information

n = number_lines/3; // number of cities

child_node_list.resize(n);
for ( int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    child_node_list[i].resize(n-1);
}

string word;
int j = 0;
int m = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<number_lines; i++)
{
    getline(Map_Data, word);

    if (i == 1 || i % 3== 1) // shows only the lines with the children nodes on
    {
        //cout << word << endl; // prints the children nodes for each parent node if needed to check
        child_node_list[j][m] == word;
        //m++;
        //j++;
    }
}
```

code changes:
for (int i = 0; i

```
        getline(Map_Data, word);


        if (i == 1 || i % 3== 1) // shows only the lines with the children nodes on
        {
            stringstream stream(word);
            for (m = 0; m = n-1; ++m)
            {
            stream >> word;
            child_node_list[j][m] = word;
            }


        //j++;

        }

    }
```

Comment: If you're looking for someone to write your code for you you've come to the wrong place, post the code you have tried.

Comment: _'I have had various attempts at this, but all unsuccessful.'_ [Elaborate your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24732353/edit) about this please.

Comment: Are you planning to apply LSI/LDA/TF-IDF etc.? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `stringstream`. It works like all other input streams, that is, using the `>>` operator will extract one word (and remove whitespace).

```
#include <sstream>

...

// After rewinding Map_Data, using seekg() or open()
for (int i = 0; i<number_lines; i++)
{
    getline(Map_Data, line_check);

    if (i % 3 == 1)
    {
        std::stringstream stream(line_check);
        for (m = 0; m < n - 1; ++m)
        {
            stream >> word;
            cout << word << endl; // if needed to check
            child_node_list[j][m] = word;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I make the changes you suggested, I get an _incomplete type is not allowed_ error on the _stream_ next to _std::stringstream_. Any ideas? I have initialised word as a string. here is my code

Comment: I have added the new code to the bottom of the code at the top

Comment: Add `#include <sstream>`?